# Dynamically load Modules? angular2

Tags: angular

We are busy building a rather large enterprise application, which has a large array of modules and components. I am sitting with an issue where I need to allow other developers in the company to develop components for this application, without them having to change the code used in the application itself.

**An example would be:**

> 'Peter' is a developer from another business unit inside the organization needs to build a charting component. We don't want Peter to change the code of the larger application, but instead, he would build and maintain his own 'Module' (these components would be built off a set interface, to allow the hosting application to communicate to the child 'chart' component) that handles all the functionality that he needs in his chart component. Inside of the larger application we would then need to be able to point to this module (through configuration) and load it dynamically.

The main point here is that I need to allow any developer to reference his own module, without my application specifically knowing about the component. I cannot have it inside my entryComponents or declarations as it needs to be loaded at runtime and should be allowed to change based on the requirements of the business unit using the application.

I have been looking at the `SystemJsNgModuleLoader`, but I see no way of loading components that aren't directly part of my application.

I am not sure if this is possible and if I have missed something somewhere. Any guidance/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Source Control**

Use Git for source control.

**Development**

Develop feature modules.  Bundle them into one UMD bundle with the source available.  This allows your developers to:

1. Target AOT for static bundles suitable for Production
2. Load dynamic modules during development

**Deployment**

Deploy your modules as a versioned package to NPM (setup an NPM repository hosted privately).

Once deployed, your developers can install, version, and manage package dependencies, just like any other NPM package:

```
npm install <package>
```